# How can I create a loop that calculates the distance traveled using Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a loop that will contain the following instructions. A loop that calculates the distance traveled outputs the result one line at a time
i.Appropriate variables must be declared and initialized. speed variable should be initialized to 75.  distance variable should be initialized to zero.
ii. Loop control variable should be called day. The day variable starts at 1 and goes up to 20. 
Here is the loop body:

1.day must be converted to hours and stored in a variable.

2.Distance traveled must be calculated. You can use the following formula: distance = time * speed.

3.distance must be incremented by 1

4.speed must be incremented by 1

5.Day, hours, speed and distance must be printed for each iteration of the loop.

I've tried a couple of ways but I haven't be able to get the same result as the picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1eqV.png

This my code at the moment

```
public static void calc(){
  System.out.println("Day \tHours \tSpeed \t Miles");

  for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
     System.out.println(i);
     }
  for (int t = 24; t <= 480; t++){
     System.out.println("\t\t"+ t);
     }
  }
```

The result is :

```
    Day     Hours   Speed    Miles
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created this code:

```
int speed = 75;
int distance = 0;
//initialize variables

System.out.print("Day\tHours\tSpeed\tMiles\n");
//print header

for (int day = 1; day <= 20; day++){
//run loop untill we pass day 20

    distance += speed * 24;
    //add speed*hoursInADay (=distance traveled that day) to distance 

    System.out.print(day + "\t" + day*24 + "\t" + speed + "\t" + distance + "\n");
    //print: day    hours   speed   distance

    speed++;
    //increment speed with 1
}
```

It works but in the solution you gave us the distance traveled jumps from 5544 to 488 from day 4 to 5, is this a mistake or?

Comment: Hi there, I'm getting downvotes for this answer and I don't know why. I'm just trying to help answer the question, and the code I gave works. So why am I getting downvoted? I would like to learn why so I can improve my future answers.

Comment: See [how to answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on meta. Some people downvote this kind of answer because providing a complete solution to somebody's homework cheats them out of the learning experience of having to write it themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it very much, your code help me understand where I'm ahead to.

Comment: @Radiodef thank you for the explination, will keep that in mind for my future answers.

Answer (score 1):

In your picture, the output is printed such that there are multiple numbers in each row. However, in your code, the second loop runs *after* the first one, so all of its output will be printed *below* the first one's. You need to print all the output in the same loop, like I've shown below. I've only shown you how to do the day and the hours, I'll leave you to figure out the rest, which should be trivial:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) { // day
    System.out.print(i + "\t");
    System.out.print(i * 24 + "\t"); // hours
    // etc.
    System.out.println(); // newline
  }
```